# github: Create a pull request to an independent repo

Tags: git, github

What we initially did was this

1) We downloaded all the code from our instructor's repository https://github.com/expertiza/expertiza
2) We created a new repository in our github account, https://github.com/saadrehman/expertiza
3) Committed all the code as our initial commit (That is lost the entire commit history)
4) Then made changes to our repository.

Now I do also have a fork of your repo in my account (https://github.com/saadrehman/expertiza-1), but that's not the repo we've been working on.

I want to communicate my changes to the professor. That is I want to issue a pull request to him, so he can merge my repo saadrehman/expertiza to his repo expertiza/expertiza - though they are not related at all, at least git doesn't know that they're related.

Currently, my remote origin is set as my personal independent repo. I could go and change it to my fork of the instructors repo (saadrehman/expertiza-1). That way I, I think I might be able to push to this fork, and then might be able to issue a pull request. But as I do it, and do git pull, I get a load of merge conflicts.

Why I think I should not get any merge conflict is that the files we touched are completely independent from the files the recent commits on the instructor's repo worked on. So I though I could just do git pull and automergind would work. But I am getting some conflicts.

Can any of you come up with any other idea? This is for school. I made the mistake of not doing a proper fork in the beginning, and now I am stuck.

Comment: That's wrong @taylorcressy, it's a Pull Request.

Comment: And you also need to swap 2 and 3 as well, the other repo can't pull from your local repository, it needs to be the remote one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have already solved this yourself since the original repository has been deleted, but you can make a Pull Request to the parent from the repository that was forked, https://github.com/saadrehman/expertiza-1, with Github's web interface.

The problem was that you made the changes as an initial commit, and I'm not sure if you downloaded the code with `git clone` or just a regular download. If you just downloaded the source it will not work and you'll get merge conflicts because it doesn't have the shared history.

The general method for using Github to handle Git merges and pull requests is:

1. Fork the upstream project.
2. Clone your new fork with `git clone`.
3. Make changes, commit them with `git commit`.
4. Push those changes to your repository with `git push origin <branch>`.
5. Send a pull request of those changes from your repository to the upstream repository.

Comment: What I ended up doing was this:

Make Another fork of the repo,
Add my files to that, 
Commit + Push etc
Crate a pull request from there.